# Basic Component Compilation error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: redhawksdr

I have installed Redhawk 1.10 on Ubuntu 14.04. I am now trying to install the basic components from the package on the github page.

I try building the SigGen component using ./reconf ./configure make make install.
During the compilation step I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: SigGen-SigGen.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Doing some searching it seems that it has something to do with linking the "libboost_system" library properly, but I do not know how to fix it.

I am running libboost-dev 1.54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic-components repository (https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/basic-components) is deprecated and the components have been broken out into individual repositories.  Please checkout the up to date SigGen repository here: https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/SigGen

The latest commit of the SigGen repository (eb19c78d10e579d267d3f796f39eae922fc65f0b) builds for me on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with a 1.10.0 framework.

The issue you are experiencing should have been fixed in the following commit, dated March 14, 2014:

```
commit db8d32c88a829272225a701752518c2b9a2a2a77
Author: Daniel Wille <daniel.wille@axiosengineering.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 14 16:35:49 2014 -0400

Fix compilation error (missing boost system library when linking) on newer OSes
```

As an FYI, the fix that was made effects the Makefile.am file.  In older commits, the  Makefile.am had this line:

```
SigGen_LDADD = $(PROJECTDEPS_LIBS) $(BOOST_LDFLAGS) $(BOOST_THREAD_LIB) $(INTERFACEDEPS_LIBS) $(redhawk_LDADD_auto)
```

While newer versions added the BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB as shown below.

```
SigGen_LDADD = $(PROJECTDEPS_LIBS) $(BOOST_LDFLAGS) $(BOOST_THREAD_LIB) $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB) $(INTERFACEDEPS_LIBS) $(redhawk_LDADD_auto)
```